# Get the page width whilst printing in javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

Is there a way to measure the page width whilst a user is printing with javascript?

I need to scale the width of an element (and its font size) based on printed page width but I can't seem to fire any Javascript at all whilst the print dialogue is open, or detect any element resize events.

Comment: you can write print media queries to change layout or style page while printing page

Comment: That's great but I can use it to measure the width of a page.

Comment: Why you want to measure the page? Tell me the purpose.